# 2-Dimensional Array with fillArray() method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I'm still pretty new to coding so I apologize in advance. But I'm working with a 2-dimensional array and can't seem to figure it out. I have the first part done but I can't figure out how to write the method (fillArray()) (when I call it in line 9 it says it's undefined but I don't know how to fix that by writing the method).

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class 2DArrays {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    2DArrays 2D = new 2dArrays();
    
    int[][] arr = 2D.fillArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            String str = "";
            if (arr[i][j] < 0) {
                str = "" + arr[i][j];
            }
            else {
                str = " " + arr[i][j];
            }
            System.out.print(" " + str);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put one loop into another, so... Here:

```
public static int[][] fillArray(){
        int[][] numbers = new int[5][10];//The array that are going to return
        
        for(int i = 1;i<=5;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j<10;j++) {
                numbers[i - 1][j] = i - j;//fill the numbers
            }
        }
        return numbers;//return result
    }
```

In main(Showing you that it's fine...?):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = fillArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
    }
```

Result:

```
[[1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8], [2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7], [3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4]]
```

Comment: The OP said the numbers come from the console in the example shown.

Comment: @WJS Ok... So... What are the inputs?

Comment: Never mind, the OP edited their question.  It has changed.

Answer (score 0):

The fillArray takes the rows and columns as arguments.

```
public static int[][] fillArray(int rows, int cols) {
    int[][] arr = new int[rows][cols];
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            arr[r][c] = r-c + 1;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

int[][] arr = fillArray(5,10);
```

An easy and formatted way to display it is

```
for (int[] r : arr) {
    for(int i : r) {
      System.out.printf("%3d",i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Prints

```
  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8
  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7
  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6
  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5
  5  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4
```